# OpenShift: Share MySQL-database between two applications

Tags: mysql, database, share, openshift

I have the following problem.

I have two application created app_1 and app_2

On app_1 MySQL is installed and has the following parameters:

```
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT = 3306
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST = 127.9.101.2
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD = xxxx
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME = xxxx
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_SOCKET = / var/lib/openshift/5252ca504382ecccc30000ca/mysql / / socket / mysql.sock
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL = mysql :/ / admindWSK1aY: bnHt58Afw69I@127.9.101.2: 3306 /
```

OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_LOG_DIR = / var/lib/openshift/5252ca504382ecccc30000ca/mysql / / log /

On app_1 I can easily connect via MySQL shell on my local database.

And command looks like this.

```
mysql -h 127.9.101.2 -u xxx -pxxx db325771
```

But when I run the same command on app_2, I get the following error message.

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can not connect to MySQL server on '127 .9.101.2 '(113)
```

What am I doing wrong?
How can I share one DB for a two apps?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You need to create app 1 as a scalable database (rhc app create myapp pyton-2.6 mysql-5 -s)

2) You need to use the URL (not the ip) for the database in app_2

That should do it for your use case

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is as follows:

1. Make a scalable application with mysql.  OpenShift does not currently expose the ports for mysql to the internet except for scalable appications.
2. In the second app, you must use the DNS of the application with mysql and the value of the OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PROXY_PORT environment variable from that application when connecting to the mysql instance in the first application.

Comment: -1, who told you to use OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PROXY_PORT? If I do env|grep OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PROXY_PORT when SSHing to my app, I do not get a result